# Last element of for each loop overwriting previous values

Tags: python

I have an issue where I need to loop through an unknown set of strings and generate a class item for each. Problem I am having and not fully understanding why is why the last element of loop is overwriting all previous values. I broke it down to a more simplified example below demonstrating the issue;

```
class Library():
    NAME = 'Library'
    def __init__(self):
        print('init')

classes = []
for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    base_node = Library
    base_node.NAME = x

    classes.append(base_node)
    print(base_node.NAME)

print('Now for full list print:')
for n in classes:
    print(n.NAME)
```

The output says:

```
a
b
c
Now for full list print:
c
c
c
```

I would expect;

```
a
b
c
Now for full list print:
a
b
c
```

Thank you for any help provided!

I have been trying multiple solution I found while searching on this forum for similar things. However, I was never able to apply any of the solution to make it work.

Comment: Search about class attributes versus instance attributes

Comment: Typo.  You want `base_node = Library()` so that you create a new `Library` object.  Right now, every element of the list is the class object, and there is only one such class.

Answer (score 4):

You've created a list of three references to the same class, with `NAME` set to `'c'`. You likely wanted to create a list of three *instances* of the `Library` class, with `name` being an instance attribute.